# Django, Python datetime.now() and storing the timezones

Tags: django, python-datetime

How does Django internally store a datetime field? Does it translate local time to UTC before storing? I am giving it a naive datetime generated from stdlib.

```
a = Message( fromm = fromm, to = to,
sent_time = datetime.datetime.now(), content = content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django ORM stores date time in your SQL database's corresponding field. The underlying SQL column is determined by the used database. E.g. for MySQL, the mappings are defined here:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py#L16

Conversion from Django to SQL:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py#L272

Conversion from SQL to Django:

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L1186](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1186)

Python `datetime.datetime.now()` is so-called timezone-naive datetime and doesn't have any timezone information. Thus, you may lose information when storing times with it and it's usage is discouraged. [It returns the local time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20now#datetime.datetime.now). It seems that that if timezone information is omitted, the Django [USE_TZ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-USE_TZ) setting determines if the [default timezone information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone) is retrofitted internally.

Instead, you should use `django.utils.timezone.now()` (local time with timezone) or `django.utils.timezone.utcnow()` (time with UTC timezone).

More info

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects

Comment: Yes, using `timezone.now()` solves my worries. And setting `TIME_ZONE` in settings will translate UTC times in DB to local times